# How to track element movement and trigger function at specific spot?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a #ball that when clicked uses jquery animate to move down 210px using this code:

```
 $('#ball').click(function() {
    $(this).animate({
        top: '+=210px'
    }, 500);
    setTimeout(crack, 400);
});​
```

currently Im using  Timeout to trigger the next function which is "crack".
Instead I want to track the movement of #ball and when its css top = 210px I want to trigger the function crack(), how can I do this?

I saw in a somewhat similar post that the Step function might be what I'm looking for, but I am not sure how to approach that solution based on the info provided at http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Look at Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/EnigmaMaster/hbvev/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure why you want to use a tracker if you know that the ball will reach the box in `210px`.

If you want to get rid of setTimeout, then use the `.animate` callback function which will be called when the ball reaches the box.

```
$('#ball').click(function() {
    $(this).animate({
        top: '+=210px'
    }, 500, crack); //<== crack will be called after ball animation
});​
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/hbvev/6/)

Incase if you want to call crack when the ball touches the box and still continue the movement of box then you can execute it 2 steps like below,

```
$('#ball').click(function() {
    $(this).animate({
        top: '+=180px'
    }, 400, function() {
        crack();
        $(this).animate({
            top: '+=30px'
        }, 100);            
    });
});
```

Also check this version for fun in slow motion http://jsfiddle.net/skram/hbvev/8/

Comment: Thanks your first suggestion was exactly what I wanted!!

Answer (score 1):

If you truly want to do something based on the position of the ball, then yes, `step` is probably the best way to go:

```
$('#ball').click(function() {
    $(this).animate({
        top: '+=210px'
    }, {
        duration: 500,
        step: function() {
            if($(this).offset().top > 208) {
                 crack();
            }                
        }
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/qJjnN/1/

Now, there are a couple of caveats:

1. There will be a possible performance hit.
2. The position at each step will not necessarily be a whole number, and the object will not exist at every pixel between the start and stop location.
3. `step` is not called on the final position, so you cannot actually check for `210` if it is the final location.

Taking those into mind, you will not be able to check for the exact position of 210px.  Instead, you will want to watch when it passes a certain position and only trigger `crack` at that point and not every point after:

```
$('#ball').click(function() {
    var cracked = false;
    $(this).animate({
        top: '+=210px'
    }, {
        duration: 500,
        step: function() {
            if($(this).offset().top > 208 && !cracked) {
                 cracked = true;
                 crack();
            }                
        }
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/qJjnN/2/

The `step` function also has parameters `now` and `fx` that can be used to see the current value of the css being animated.  `step` is called for each step of each css attribute being animated.  So, you have to be careful using those, because you need to look at `fx` to see what attribute value you are looking at (if you are animating more than one, i.e. `top` and `left`).

```
$('#ball').click(function() {
    var cracked = false;
    $(this).animate({
        top: '+=210px'
    }, {
        duration: 500,
        step: function(now, fx) {
            if(fx.prop != 'top') {
                 return;
            }
            if(now > 208 && !cracked) {
                 cracked = true;
                 crack();
            }                
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: your first demo is triggering the crack function multiple times and causing the boxes to spread out more with each triggering , causing a neat firework burst, not sure if that was intentional but i like it